# Does net.createServer() method return net.Server or net.Socket?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am new to socket programming. I am going through the `net` API documentation here : https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener

I am confused whether the method `net.createServer()` returns `<net.Server>` or `<net.Socket>`. As mentioned in the API documentation, it returns `<net.Server>`. But from the example provided, it looks like it returns `<net.Socket>` as the callback param reads and write the stream using `pipe()` method and also no `end` event registered by `net.Server`.

Please refer the following code provided by API doc

```
const server = net.createServer((c) => {
  // 'connection' listener
  console.log('client connected');
  c.on('end', () => {
    console.log('client disconnected');
  });
  c.write('hello\r\n');
  c.pipe(c);
});
```

Comment: `server` is a server, `c` is a socket.

Comment: @Ryan As the net.createServer() is an asynchronous function, I hope it can return its value only to the callback param. Please clarify!

Comment: It’s a function that you pass to `net.createServer` that’s called with a socket object every time a connection is made to the server. A value isn’t “returned” to it and passing a function to a function doesn’t stop it from returning a value.